# Set Up Tailwind css (React + Django) - can't figure it out

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, tailwind-css

I'm using react and django for one of my projects. I managed to frontend and backend together but there is a question, how to get tailwind work for react in the same time. I used https://www.valentinog.com/blog/drf/ articule to set up system.

Can't figure out this one. Maybe someone is using this kinda stack and could help.

Basically I went through tailwind react installation from docs, here is files, what i am end up with.

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "2roka",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --entry ./otraroka/frontend/src/index.js --output-path ./otraroka/frontend/static/frontend/ & craco start",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --entry ./otraroka/frontend/src/index.js --output-path ./otraroka/frontend/static/frontend/ & craco build",
    "test": "craco test"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^5.13.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.0.0",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**when I ran command *npm run dev* i got an error -  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'react-scripts/package.json'**

Probably wrong set up with dictionaries, but cant figure out, how it [image]should be.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation? Could you show what you have currently, and what's not working out?

Comment: @juliomalves add some information about project

Comment: That error looks unrelated to TailwindCSS. You seem to be using `craco` in your npm scripts but don't have it your dependencies. Might want to add that.